# How to get all GIT branches monitored by TFS CI?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, visual-studio-2013

Team Foundation Server 2013 offers a Continuous Integration build service. In the process of settings this up in Visual Studio 2013, I ran into dialog for selecting GIT branches to watch:

[image: The dialog window]

What should I do if I want to trigger the build for all commits?

Comment: Did you check the 'Process' tab, which may have additional settings? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/01/30/getting-started-with-git-in-visual-studio-and-team-foundation-service.aspx?PageIndex=3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out! I can write `refs/heads/*` into `Include` section. Every name is going to be matched by the star.

Comment: I have the same problem in configuring CI with Git. What did you use at the process tab? Thanks man.

Comment: Oh, nothing special there -- I just set right msbuild file and tuned build number format. It's all about setting Include:refs/heads/* as the Source Settings tab.

Answer (score -1):

You can Work with the "Exclude" in the branches and exclude a single branch. All Others will be tracked

Comment: Really? I thought is used this